# Android Studio Java Firebase retrieve key from CardView

Tags: java, firebase, android-recyclerview, key, google-cloud-firestore

So I've been searching the WHOLE internet for a solution but NONE worked for me sadly.
My goal is to retrieve the data from the cardView which is stored on Firebase and use that data when the cardView is clicked to display it on a new Activity.

I've created "Posts" as a collection, so all of the data such as header, date, image etc are stored inside the "Posts" collection.

From my understanding, what I need to do is to retrieve the key from the cardView data that has been clicked and use it to implement the same data on the new activity using the same mutual key.

I'm stuck here for ages, I would LOVE to get some help.. thanks alot!

My code -

RecyclerAdapter -

```
public class PostsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<PostsAdapter.ViewHolder> {



public List<ListForPost> list_post;

public Context context;


public PostsAdapter(List<ListForPost> list_post) {

    this.list_post = list_post;

}


@NonNull
@Override
public PostsAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.posts_intro, parent, false);
    context = parent.getContext();



    return new ViewHolder(view);
}



@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final PostsAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    String header_data = list_post.get(position).getHeader();
    holder.setHeaderText(header_data);

    String date_data = list_post.get(position).getDate1();
    holder.setDateText(date_data);

    String image_data = list_post.get(position).getImage_url();
    holder.setIntroIMG(image_data);

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return list_post.size();
}


public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    private View mView;

    private ImageView introIMG;
    private TextView headerText;
    private TextView dateText;


    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {

        super(itemView);
        mView = itemView;

    }

    public void setHeaderText(String headText) {

        headerText = mView.findViewById(R.id.introHeader);
        headerText.setText(headText);

    }

    public void setDateText(String tarihText) {

        dateText = mView.findViewById(R.id.introDate);
        dateText.setText(tarihText);

    }

    public void setIntroIMG (String downloadUri) {

        introIMG = (ImageView) mView.findViewById(R.id.introImage);
        Glide.with(context).load(downloadUri).into(introIMG);
    }
}
```

}

MainActivity -

```
firebaseFirestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    firebaseFirestore.collection("Posts").limit(10).addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onEvent(QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots, FirebaseFirestoreException e) {

            for (DocumentChange doc: queryDocumentSnapshots.getDocumentChanges()) {
                if (doc.getType() == DocumentChange.Type.ADDED) {
                    ListForPost listForPost = doc.getDocument().toObject(ListForPost.class);
                    list_post.add(listForPost);
                    postsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: simply add query on click .! and on data received open other activity

Comment: Can you give me an example please? My problem is to send and receive the same data.. opening new activity isnt the hard part

Comment: post your node structure.!

Comment: you can do two thing first get all post data and then use only title in your cardview and when ever you click on your recycleview card get that object and send it to other activity

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be set an OnClickListener for mView inside of your ViewHolder. So for your code that would be something like this:

```
public class PostsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<PostsAdapter.ViewHolder> {
     //...

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        private View mView;
        private ListForPost mListForPost;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            mView = itemView;

            mView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick() {
                    //TODO: launch my activity here with mListForPost
                }
            });
        }

        private void setListForPost(ListForPost listForPost) {
            mListForPost = listForPost;
        }

        //...
    }
}
```

If you want to make this even nicer (so you don't have to deal with how to call startActivity() or pass in Context as a parameter to your ViewHolder) you can abstract out the details with another listener, maybe a "ListForPostClickedListener":

```
public class PostsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<PostsAdapter.ViewHolder> {
     //...

     private ListForPostClickedListener mListForPostClickedListener;

     public PostsAdapter(ListForPostClickedListener listForPostClickedListener) {
        mListForPostClickedListener = listForPostClickedListener;
     }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        //...

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            //...

            mView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick() {
                    mListForPostClickedListener.onClick(mListForPost);
                }
            });
        }

        //...
    }

    public interface ListForPostClickedListener {
        void onClick(ListForPost listForPost);
    }
}
```

And in the Activity, Fragment or whatever other context-aware object you use your PostsAdapter from, you implement the interface and launch the necessary Activity:

```
public class MyActivityWhichManagesTheAdapter extends Activity implements PostsAdapter.ListForPostClickedListener {

    //...

    public onClick(ListForPost listForPost) {
      //TODO: launch my activity here with mListForPost
    }

}
```

Comment: Hey, I'm sorry but I didn't understand.. how can I get the data on activity 1 and send it to the other activity?